# Update the plugin will be something wrong

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

When I update the Laravel plugin, if I use some static method e.g. `User::find($id)` it will show a warning: "Non-static method User::find() should not be called statically", this very bad!

Example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Model\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use EasyWeChat\Foundation\Application;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Application $wechat)
    {
        parent::__construct($wechat);
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(12);
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: which plugin you updated? What is your laravel version

Comment: Check namespace of `User` class and does `User` class extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class?

Comment: Please try with $user = DB::table('users')->where('id',12)->get(); and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::all()->find(12);
    dd($user);
}
```

Comment: Yes,It`s a right way,But why?Not long ago can use like that,But it`s waring now?

Comment: maybe try updating the Phpstorm version you have to (phpstrom 2017.2). it should fix it